# Is there any way to slip a _Static_assert into an expression in ISO C11?

Tags: c, c11

In C11 it is legal to write, for instance:

```
int b = (some_function_returning_void(), 1020);
```

And you'll get back 1020.  But it won't let you write:

```
int b = (_Static_assert(2 > 1, "all is lost"), 304);
```

gcc returning

```
error: expected expression before '_Static_assert'
```

And it would be inconvenient to use `_Static_assert` outside of an expression sometimes since you're out of luck with preprocessor macros-based pseudo-functions that verify their arguments then.

Comment: `static_assert` is meant to be usable outside functions, too. Therefore syntactically it can't be an expression. But for my curiosity, I didn't really get why you would need that, and cannot just place it before the declaration.

Comment: Do you have a more concrete example of where you would use this?  There may be a better way.

Comment: my guess is a *function-like macro*? Within a macro you can use a *very crude* trick - a bitfield with negative width for example, this will fail at compile time because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't quite see why you need this, but you _could_ create a function containing nothing but a static assert. The optimizer will remove it since it contains no run-rime code.

Comment: Functions can't access their callee's variables, so i can't assert over anything but global consts this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is doable in ISO C11. The trick is to put `_Static_assert` in a struct declaration, in a sizeof expression:

```
sizeof(struct { _Static_assert(0, "yay it failed"); int dummy; })
```

The dummy field is necessary because `empty struct is a GNU extension`, according to `clang -std=c11 -Weverything`.

Comment: Nice hack. Too bad it turns out gcc thinks `const` variables that are assigned constant values aren't in fact constants, so i can't use them in static asserts.

Comment: @L29Ah: That's not just something "gcc thinks". That's how C language is defined. In C `const` variables do not form constant expressions.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to make a wrapper macro that works in both expression and declaration contexts

Comment: this doesn't work for MSVC.... is there a workaround?

Answer (score 7):

`_Static_assert` is, unfortunately, a special kind of *declaration*, not a function or an operator. You won't be able to slip it into an expression, unless you use something non-standard. E.g. compiler extensions like GCC's "statement expressions"

```
int b = ({ _Static_assert(2 > 1, "all is lost"); 304; });
```

or

```
int b = (({ _Static_assert(2 > 1, "all is lost"); }), 304);
```