# How to static_assert in an expression out of function bodies in C

Tags: c, macros, static-assert

I am writing a macro `PAGE_ALIGN` in C as follows.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define PAGE_ALIGN(x) ((x) & 0xfffff000U)

int main() {
    printf("0x%08x\n", PAGE_ALIGN(0x12345678U));
}
```

Now I want to make sure that the user is passing in the correct type to `PAGE_ALIGN`. I use `_Static_assert()` to perform the assertion, and things work well.

```c
#define PAGE_ALIGN(x) (({_Static_assert(sizeof(x) == 4); x;}) & 0xfffff000U)
```

However, some of my code does not use `PAGE_ALIGN` in functions. For example, when defining a global variable:

```c
char a[PAGE_ALIGN(0x12345678U)];
```

Then I get the compile error

```
a.c:3:24: error: braced-group within expression allowed only inside a function
    3 | #define PAGE_ALIGN(x) (({_Static_assert(sizeof(x) == 4); x;}) & 0xfffff000U)
      |                        ^
a.c:5:8: note: in expansion of macro 'PAGE_ALIGN'
    5 | char a[PAGE_ALIGN(0x12345678U)];
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a way to define `PAGE_ALIGN` such that the macro works outside of a function?

Complete `a.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define PAGE_ALIGN(x) (({_Static_assert(sizeof(x) == 4); x;}) & 0xfffff000U)

char a[PAGE_ALIGN(0x12345678U)];

int main() {
    printf("0x%08x\n", PAGE_ALIGN(0x12345678U));
}
```

---

**Update:** here is the motivation for this question.

I am writing an OS that deals with physical address and virtual address in 32-bit and 64-bit mode. Virtual addresses are 32 bits in 32-bit mode and 64 bits in 64-bit mode. So `unsigned long` is used for virtual addresses. Physical addresses are always 64 bits, so `unsigned long long` is used. I am writing a header file that distinguishes these different types

For example, page size macros are:

```c
#define VA_PAGE_SIZE_4K 0x1000UL  // VA for virtual address
#define PA_PAGE_SIZE_4K 0x1000ULL // PA for physical address
```

Then I define macros for aligning up:

```c
#define VA_PAGE_ALIGN_UP_4K(x) (((x) + VA_PAGE_SIZE_4K - 1) & ~(VA_PAGE_SIZE_4K - 1))
#define PA_PAGE_ALIGN_UP_4K(x) (((x) + PA_PAGE_SIZE_4K - 1) & ~(PA_PAGE_SIZE_4K - 1))
```

Please imagine that there are other macros, such as `VA_PAGE_ALIGN_UP_2M`, `VA_PAGE_ALIGN_UP_1G`, ...

My OS has a fixed supported physical address size (say 4 GiB) and I want to need an identity map page table. So I can use the alignment macros to compute how many page table entries I need to support. Of course, there are page directories etc. due to multi-level paging.

```c
// maximum physical memory, 4G
#define MAX_PHYS_MEM 0x100000000ULL

// number of page table entries
#define PAGE_TABLE_NELEMS (PA_PAGE_ALIGN_UP_4K(MAX_PHYS_MEM) / PA_PAGE_SIZE_4K)

// Define page table (global variable)
unsigned long page_table[PAGE_TABLE_NELEMS];

// number of page directory entries
#define PAGE_DIRECTORY_NELEMS (PA_PAGE_ALIGN_UP_2M(MAX_PHYS_MEM) / PA_PAGE_SIZE_2M)

// Define page directory (global variable)
unsigned long page_directory[PAGE_DIRECTORY_NELEMS];

// ...
```

However, in other code I want to make sure that `PA_PAGE_ALIGN_UP_4K` and `VA_PAGE_ALIGN_UP_4K` are not mixed. That is, `PA_PAGE_ALIGN_UP_4K` only used on `unsigned long long` and `VA_PAGE_ALIGN_UP_4K` only used on `unsigned long`. So I want to add a static assert in those macros. But adding a static assert will cause compile errors in `page_table` and `page_directory` above.

Comment: Why do you care which *type* is given as the array size?

Comment: I care about the type in other use cases to `PAGE_ALIGN`, and there happens to be array size calculation code using the same macro.

Comment: Then you should show *that* code, because it smells like an XY-problem.

Comment: If you care about size of an array to satisfy a certain constraint, you can use the static assert on the `sizeof a` *after* it was declared/defined.

Comment: You can put the `static_assert()` inside a `struct` declaration inside a `sizeof()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263525/502399

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tavian Barnes's comment solves my problem. My updated program looks like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define PAGE_ALIGN(x) (sizeof(struct { _Static_assert(sizeof(x) == 4); int dummy; }) * 0 + ((x) & 0xfffff000U))

char a[PAGE_ALIGN(0x12345678U)];

int main() {
    printf("0x%08x\n", PAGE_ALIGN(0x12345678U));
}
```